# What does "custom data" in this context means?

Tags: html, custom-data-attribute

I was reading on the W3C school website about the `data-*` attribute and I read this:

> "The data-* attributes is used to store custom data private to the
>   page or application. The data-* attributes gives us the ability to
>   embed custom data attributes on all HTML elements."

What does "custom data" mean in this context?

Comment: For quality information use MDN instead. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/

Comment: Meta-data would have been a wiser word. Basically data that has to do with the item you're displaying, but useless in the context of rendering it. For example, in a mixed list of fruits and vegetables, it might be helpfull to distinguish between ones and others. Typically before we used custom tags or even css classes, nowadays data-attibutes are the must for this.

Answer (score 1):

Beyond the available attributes in the specification, you might need additional information to store on elements. Before, people made up their own attribute names and put that in the tag, but that gave problems when validating the HTML for example.

Nowadays, there is a standard to provide 'custom' attributes, the `data-` attributes. This way the validator knows what to do, and you as a developer has the freedom to add attributes if you need them.

Old invalid syntax sample (does not validate!):

```
<input somevariable="somevalue" />
```

New and improved and perfectly valid due to the `data-` prefix:

```
<input data-somevariable="somevalue" />
```